# Changing selected columnn types to percentage while writing pandas df to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am writing multiple sheets in to excel file using pandas:

```
df_res = {'name' : df_1,
          'name_2': df_2}

sheet_names = ['first','second']

with pd.ExcelWriter('my_file.xlsx') as writer:  
    for new_name, (name,df) in zip(sheet_names, df_res.items()):
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = new_name)
```

My structure of multiple `dfs` is that they are in a dictionary. In each of those two `dfs` there are certain columns which format I would like to change to a percentage - same as selecting a column in excel and click on `%` sign to convert it to percentage type.

I achieve the formatting by adding the following to my for loop:

```
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[new_name]
format_percentages = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
# below I change a single column type
worksheet.set_column('J:J', 18, format_percentages)
```

The problem is that my wanted columns do not appear in the same order. if below were my `dfs`:

```
# df_1
A               B               C               # immitating excel column names
name            sales           difference
A               10              50

# df_2
A               B               C               # immitating excel column names
name            difference      sales
B               10              50
```

I could not call the format on column `B` or `C` since `difference` which I would like to be represented as percentage type appears in different columns.

Is there a way to change column type by giving its column name?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"name": {0: "A"}, "sales": {0: 10}, "difference": {0: 50}})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({"name": {0: "B"}, "difference": {0: 10}, "sales": {0: 50}})


df_res = {"name": df_1, "name_2": df_2}

sheet_names = ["first", "second"]

with pd.ExcelWriter("my_file.xlsx") as writer:
    for new_name, (name, df) in zip(sheet_names, df_res.items()):
        for col in ["sales", "difference"]:
            df[col] = pd.Series(
                ["{0:.2f}%".format(val) for val in df[col]], index=df.index
            )
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=new_name)
```

Which outputs an Excel files with both columns "difference" and "sales" formatted as percentages on both sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`columns.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) which giving a column name, returns the integer location for the requested label. You can then use [`set_column`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html) using the previous value on `first_col` and `last_col`:

> To apply a style to a single column the value of `first_col` and `last_col` should be the same:
> worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 30)  # Width of column B set to 30.

```py
    ...
    ...
    for new_name, (name,df) in zip(sheet_names, df_res.items()):
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets[new_name]
        format_percentages = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})

        col_idx = df.columns.get_loc('difference')
        worksheet.set_column(col_idx, col_idx, 18, format_percentages)

        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = new_name)
```